# Problem creating a stream with kubernetes

Tags: linux, kubernetes

I'm trying to create a stream with Kubernetes and MistServer. For this, I have a video hosted in a folder called 'videos.' It's located at the path '/videos.' I created this folder as a shared folder using the following command:
`mkdir -p $PWD/videos`
First, I start Minikube with 'minikube start.' Then I use 'minikube mount /videos:/videos.'

Next, I create a YAML file with the following content:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mist-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mist-container
    image: ddvtech/mistserver
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
    - containerPort: 4242
    - containerPort: 1935
    volumeMounts:
    - name: videos
      mountPath: /video
    - name: dshm
      mountPath: /dev/shm
  volumes:
  - name: videos
    hostPath:
      path: /videos
  - name: dshm
    emptyDir:
      medium: Memory
```

I execute 'kubectl apply -f mist-pod.yaml.'

I access 'http://192.168.49.2:4242,' which is the MistServer, and try to create the stream. When I attempt to create it as a source, the video that I previously mounted to its folder does not appear. Consequently, the final command 'mpv "http://192.168.49.2:8080/hls/mist/index.m3u8"' doesn't work.

Any idea why it doesn't work?

I try to change the yaml file and also to create the folder several times.